# Pandas DataFrame, can't use built in function - unsupported operand type

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, I am learning Pandas DataFrame and trying to get difference row-wise.
Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
short_window = 40
long_window = 100
signals = pd.DataFrame(index=aapl.index)
signals['signal'] = 0.0

signals['short_mavg'] = aapl['Adj Close'].rolling(window = short_window, min_periods=1, center=False).mean()
signals['long_mavg'] = aapl['Adj Close'].rolling(window = long_window, min_periods=1, center=False).mean()
signals.fillna(0, inplace=True)

signals['signal'][short_window:] = np.where(signals['short_mavg'][short_window:] > signals['long_mavg'][short_window:], 1.0, 0.0)
```

Everything is OK for now, this is what i have so far.

[image]

And next thing I want to do is to calculate difference between next rows (second and first, third and second and so on) and put it in new column like this:

```
signals['positions'] = signals['signal'].diff()
```

This is the error I get:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'

Comment: Hi Falco Peregrinus, welcome to SO. Please read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong with your data set, your code should work. For some reason in your `signals['signal']` you have a mix of float and methods. Here's a complete code that should work for anyone:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl as qdl

qdl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'your key' # freely available, registration is needed

signals = qdl.get("WIKI/AAPL")
signals['signal'] = 0.0
signals['short_mavg'] = signals['Adj. Close'].rolling(window = short_window, min_periods=1, center=False).mean()
signals['long_mavg'] = signals['Adj. Close'].rolling(window = long_window, min_periods=1, center=False).mean()
signals['signal'][short_window:] = np.where(signals['short_mavg'][short_window:] > signals['long_mavg'][short_window:], 1.0, 0.0)
signals['positions'] = signals['signal'].diff()
```

Check if it works for you.

Comment: Your code works for me. Thank you very much. BTW, i am getting my data from yahoo like this: `df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)`
I have two problems now, first not so important, Quandl WIKI Prices Datasets is no longer being updated.   
And second, I am currently working with sp500, so I have list of tickers (simbols of companies). How should I get all data if I have to use ("WIKI/ticker_name")
I have tried like this:
`for ticker in tickers:
qdl.get("WIKI/" + ticker)`
but it is not working

Comment: And i get this error
NotFoundError: (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.

Comment: @FalcoPeregrinus Have you registered on Quandl and got API key? We can have a chat how on to resolve these problems, but I'd avoid scope creep here. Accept the answer on this one (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and we can move on.

Comment: Yes, I did. And that code works for me if I use only one ticker, but not if I make list of tickers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had to write code like this:

```
signals['signal'][short_window:] = np.where(signals['short_mavg'][short_window:] > signals['long_mavg'][short_window:], 1.0, 0.0)
```

Without breaking code in lines. I am writing this in jupyter notebook, because I have just started to learn, and it is is easier to write comments and also I am splitting code because it is easier to read, and this is the first time I had problem with it.